# Changing order of derivation and integration for infinitely continuous function

Tags: integration, derivatives

$$\frac d{dt}\int_0^t f(t,\tau)d\tau=f(t,t)+\int_0^t\frac\partial{\partial t}f(t,\tau)d\tau$$

How would you prove that? Thank you very much

Comment: You would replace $\tau$ with $t$ and then bring the derivative inside the integral (so that it becomes a partial derivative) per the Newton-Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when can we interchange integration and differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530213/when-can-we-interchange-integration-and-differentiation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Newton-Leibniz Integral rule

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{s(t)}f(t,\tau)d\tau=s'(t)\, f(s(t),t)+\int_a^{s(t)}\frac{\partial f(t,\tau)} {\partial t }  \, d\tau$$

in your case $s(t)=t$ and $a=0$. Therefore, $s'(t)=1$ and the above expression becomes

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{t}f(t,\tau)d\tau=\, f(t,t)+\int_0^{t}\frac{\partial f(t,\tau)} {\partial t }  \, d\tau$$

Comment: Thank you very much, do you think is possible to show that by the definition of derivative ? I am afraid we are not allowed to use NL rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Or use any of the [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530213/when-can-we-interchange-integration-and-differentiation/2530224#2530224) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241942/partial-derivative-of-integral-leibniz-rule) to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097204/derivative-of-parametric-integral-using-leibniz) and [variants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731103/proof-of-leibniz-integral-rule-for-2-variable-function) of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050019/minimal-conditions-for-leibniz-rule-for-changing-the-integral-and-derivative) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439510/leibniz-rule-for-partial-derivative) [on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252568/interchange-of-integral-and-partial-derivative-in-measure-theory) this site.

Comment: I am not really sure what to ....